# The type was not found compilation error in GWT Super Dev Mode

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I upgraded to GWT 2.6.0 to test Super Dev Mode.

My application compiles OK when compiled for production (using GPE) and also runs OK on Dev Mode.

However when I try to compile it in Super Dev mode I get errors.

```
workDir: /var/folders/9l/zfcsrq790mn8__7q1cy5_7gh0000gn/T/gwt-codeserver-3316577908252534936.tmp
binding: user.agent=safari
binding: compiler.useSourceMaps=true
binding: locale=en
Compiling module com.juntosalimos.Junsal
   Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ApplicationController'
      Rebinding com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ApplicationController
         Invoking generator com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ApplicationControllerGenerator
            [ERROR] The type 'com.juntosalimos.client.gin.PreBootstrapperImpl' was not found.
[ERROR] Compiler returned false
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.ModuleState.<init>(ModuleState.java:58)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeModules(CodeServer.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:49)
```

Any ideas what are the differences between the SDM compiler and the production compiler?
I am using this as arguments to the codeserver:

-src src/ com.juntosalimos.Junsal

Comment: Does it change anything if you put `src/` in your classpath (like with DevMode and Compiler) instead of using the `-src` argument?